# I am trying to validate jsp login form,I need field (label) validation instead of alert message

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, jsp

Here is my javascript:

```
function checkEmail() {

    var email = document.getElementById('mLoginName');


    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})|([0-9]{10})+$/;


    if (!filter.test(email.value)) {
        alert("Please enter valid email id or 10 digit mobile number");
        email.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<form:form method="post" onsubmit="return checkEmail();" action="SignIn"  modelAttribute="memberBean" >
    <form:input type='hidden' name='mode' id='mode' path='mode' />
    <form:input type='text'  class="input" name='mLoginName'  id='mLoginName' path='mLoginName' onblur="checkInp()" placeholder='Email/Mobile' />

<input type='submit' class="submit" value='SignIn/SignUp' >
</form:form>
```

Comment: In case you're interested,  you could look at the jQuery Validate plugin which has handy tools for dealing with client-side validation: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: HTML Code:<form:form method="post" onsubmit="return checkEmail();" action="SignIn"  modelAttribute="memberBean" >
 <form:input type='hidden' name='mode' id='mode' path='mode' />
 
 <form:input type='text'  class="input" name='mLoginName'  id='mLoginName' path='mLoginName' onblur="checkInp()" placeholder='Email/Mobile'  />
 <span id="mLoginValidate"></span>
<input type='submit' class="submit" value='SignIn/SignUp' >
</form:form>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add a `<span id="mLoginValidate"></span>` ( or a `<p></p>` depending on how you want it to look ) after your input, and then in your code, add

```
document.getElementById('mLoginValidate').innerHTML = "Please enter valid email id or 10 digit mobile number";
```

You can also change its css to `display: none` when the user starts re-typing, and then change it back do `display: block` upon failed validation.

Here's a little fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/virginieLGB/h600vecx/

Here's what I've done:
**HTML:**

```
<input type='text'  ... onkeydown="hideError()" />
<span id="mLoginValidate">Please enter valid email id or 10 digit mobile number</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
span {
  color: red;
  display: none;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function hideError() {
    document.getElementById("mLoginValidate").style.display = "none";
}
```

*And in your checkEmail() function*:

```
document.getElementById("mLoginValidate").style.display = "block";
```

Comment: Can you please explain me where to add span tag in code. I tried but am not getting Error message.

Comment: Add your HTML to your post, otherwise I can't help. But basically put it right after your input

Comment: HTML Code looks like:<form:form method="post" onsubmit="return checkEmail();" action="SignIn"  modelAttribute="memberBean" >
 <form:input type='hidden' name='mode' id='mode' path='mode' />
 
 <form:input type='text'  class="input" name='mLoginName'  id='mLoginName' path='mLoginName' onblur="checkInp()" placeholder='Email/Mobile'  />
 
<input type='submit' class="submit" value='SignIn/SignUp' >
</form:form>

Comment: I've just edited my answer and added a fiddle for you to try